# How to add tracking ID link in shipping email?

Tags: magento2, shipment-tracking

I like to add tracking ID link for my shipping email template form. 
Please advice me to do this process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please override this file:

**vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml**

by creating this path:

**/app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/shipment/track.phtml**

Please add below code in foreach loop

```
<?php
$trackurl = '';
if($_item->getCarrierCode() === 'fedex'){
    $trackurl = 'https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?action=track&trackingnumber='.$_item->getNumber();
}elseif ($_item->getCarrierCode() === 'usps') {
    $trackurl = 'https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction_input?qtc_tLabels1='.$_item->getNumber();
}elseif ($_item->getCarrierCode() === 'ups') {
    $trackurl = 'https://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/returnToDetails?tracknum='.$_item->getNumber();
}
?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getCarrierCode()) ?>:</td>

     <td style="padding:3px 9px"><a href="<?php echo $trackurl ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getNumber()) ?></a></td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The better option for M2.4 is to replace Tracking Url Handler with a layout, doing something like that:

**app/code/Local/Shipping/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_shipment_track.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.email.shipment.track">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="tracking_url" xsi:type="object">Local\Shipping\Block\DataProviders\Email\Shipment\TrackingUrl</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Local/Shipping/Block/DataProviders/Email/Shipment/TrackingUrl.php**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Local\Shipping\Block\DataProviders\Email\Shipment;

use Magento\Sales\Block\DataProviders\Email\Shipment\TrackingUrl as Core;

class TrackingUrl extends Core
{
    /**
     * Get Shipping tracking URL
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Track $track
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Track $track): string
    {
        if ($track->getCarrierCode() === 'something') {
            return 'https://some.url' . '?' . http_build_query(['param' => $track->getNumber()]);
        } else {
            return parent::getUrl($track);
        }
    }
}
```